# How to upload picture to picturebox and save it in SQL Server using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to know how I could browse picture on desktop and upload the pic to my form and then save it to my database. This is what my friend did but it doesn't work for me. I don't know why please help.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox11.Image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tblperson([product name],[pics],[user]) VALUES(@value1,@value2,@value3)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", txtproductname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", picbase64);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", lbluser.Text);

cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Picture Saved");

con.Close();

txtproductname.Text = "";
pictureBox11.Image = LessonMidterm1.Properties.Resources.Person;
```

Comment: Please *clarify your specific problem* or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just use VARBINARY type to store images to DB.
You can easily get bytes from memory stream (`ToArray()` metod) and store then in DB.

Comment: sorry @SergeyBerezovskiy . I wasn't able to add other information awhile ago. my problem is that I want to know how i could browse pictures on desktop and upload a pic to my form or picturebox and then save it to my database. The codes above are the codes my friend made with her system but it doesn't work on mine. please help

Comment: It's not clear what '*it doesn't work on me*' means

Comment: it works on her system but it doesn't on mine. it has errors.

Comment: @MonarchL like this? MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox11.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Byte[] picarray = ms.ToArray();
            String picbase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(picarray);

Comment: ***WHAT*** errors do you get? We can't read your screen - nor your mind - you'll have to **show us!**